# Spree - creating a Preferences page per store/language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Is it possible to create a "site-wide" preferences page per store/language?

I was looking at `Spree::Preferences::Configuration`

Is it possible to create it with this extend?

Comment: I'm also currently working on Spree. I'm n00b although. But if you elaborate your need a more, then I might give it a try... :)

Comment: I'd like to create a settings page for items on the homepage, for example 'featured_products'. I want to manage these settings per store. I have no clue where to begin ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add some functionality to [Spree::Store](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.3/core/app/models/spree/store.rb) to do all sorts of stuff. Without more details, it will be difficult to provide anything more than that.